# find a pattern and replace it with same pattern on a new line

Tags: regex, notepad++

Have this:

```
Array ( [0] => Tiger [first_name] => Tiger [1] => Nixon [last_name] => Nixon [2] => Accountant [position] => Accountant [3] => Tokyo [office] => Tokyo [4] => 2016-11-08 [start_date] => 2016-11-08 [5] => 320800 [salary] => 320800 ) Array ( [0] => Garrett [first_name] => Garrett [1] => Winters [last_name] => Winters [2] => Accountant2 [position] => Accountant2 [3] => Tokyo [office] => Tokyo [4] => 2016-11-08 [start_date] => 2016-11-08 [5] => 170750 [salary] => 170750 ) Array ( [0] => Ashton [first_name] => Ashton [1] => Cox [last_name] => Cox [2] => Accountant3 [position] => Accountant3 [3] => Tokyo [office] => Tokyo [4] => 2016-11-08 [start_date] => 2016-11-08 [5] => 86000 [salary] => 86000 ) Array ( [0] => Cedric [first_name] => Cedric [1] => Kelly [last_name] => Kelly [2] => Accountant4 [position] => Accountant4 [3] => Tokyo [office] => Tokyo [4] => 2016-11-08 [start_date] => 2016-11-08 [5] => 433060 [salary] => 433060 )
```

Want it to look like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Tiger [first_name] => Tiger 
[1] => Nixon [last_name] => Nixon 
[2] => Accountant [position] => Accountant 
[3] => Tokyo [office] => 
...
```

In notepad++ usng regex

Answer (score 0):

Find this: 
`\[(\d)\]`
And replace with this 
`\n\[$1\]`

---

`\[(\d)\]`      - this finds this pattern `[0]` or `[1]` ... 
`(\d)`          - this captures the value inside the squar brackets: `0` or `1` ...

---

`\n\[$1\]`  - this puts a new line before the open square bracket, `$1` is what was captured in the brackets `()` in the find above and replaced here, and then finished with a `]` square bracket.

---

**NOTE** note the `\` escaping on the square brackets e.g. `\[`

Comment: It would be simpler to include the square-brackets in the capture. So, search for `(\[\d\])` and replace with `\n\1`.

Comment: tks, for my ref. `\n$1` is the same as `\n\1`

Answer (score 0):

The other answer plus:

```
Find What: " Array"
Replace With: "\nArray"
```

To also have each of your Array on new line.